# Tabulator / programmatically correct table data (loaded from HTML <table>)

Tags: javascript, tabulator

The `Tabulator` is created from an *unknown* `HTML <table>` (which has TH headers, so all columns have names).

As a consequence, there's no way to trigger any `mutator` or  `callback`... except `htmlImported:function()`.

Because the `HTML <table>` contains wrongly formatted DATE values, I need to access all `fields` of all `rows` to spot and correct these.

The whole code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/css/">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<table id="tablexxx">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th><th>Favorite Color</th><th>date</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Bob</td><td>Yellow</td><td>1/1/2001</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>Michelle</td><td>Purple</td><td>2/1/2000</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="tablexxx"></div>

<script>
var tablexxx = new Tabulator("#tablexxx", {});

var rows = tablexxx.getRows();
rows.forEach(function(row)
{ var rowData = row.getData();
  rowData.forEach(function(cell) // <<< HOW TO DO IT RIGHT???
  {
    // get row field NAME
    var field = cell.name;       // <<< HOW TO DO IT RIGHT???
    if(field.indexOf("date") >= 0)
    {
       // get colum field VALUE
       var date = cell.value;   // <<< HOW TO DO IT RIGHT???

       // make new value using proper format
       var ndate = date[0] + date[1] + date[2]; // TODO

       // update row with {"date":"01/02/2000"}
       row.update("{" + field + ":" + ndate + "}"); 
    }
  });
});
</script></body></html>
```

Can someone tell me how to `"DO IT RIGHT"` for the specified `<script>` portions above that are lagging?

Comment: The question has been edited to bring everything, thank you!

Comment: As explained in the question, data is imported from the static HTML table, see: "Create from HTML Table Element" as in http://tabulator.info/examples/4.3?#table-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand what you wanted to accomplish...

This pads the day and month with 0, if the it is < 10.

First get the column with the data field, then iterate over every cell in that column, split the date and update the cell.
I don't actually know why there is an empty row in the table (that is what `if (value)`is for). It is something inserted by tabulator.

```js
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

var tablexxx = new Tabulator("#tablexxx", {});
var dateColumn = tablexxx.getColumn("date");
for (var cell of dateColumn.getCells()) {
  var value = cell.getValue();
  if (value) {
    value = value.split("/")
    cell.setValue(pad(value[0], 2) + "/" + pad(value[1], 2) + "/" + value[2]);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/css/">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablexxx">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th><th>Favorite Color</th><th>date</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Bob</td><td>Yellow</td><td>1/1/2001</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>Michelle</td><td>Purple</td><td>2/1/2000</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! As shown in the question, I will actually have to find which column title contains "date" but your reply provided me with the part that I could not write myself, so, thank you again!

Comment: Note: this solution works only on the VISIBLE rows of a table - it would be great to have a more global solution. Anyone?

Comment: FYI, I resolved the problem by editing the HTML <table> with Javascript before importing it with Tabulator. This is much faster and works as expected.